# Export Custom options in Magento 2.1.4 CE

Tags: magento-2.1, custom-options

I am working on my own store locally in wamp64 and windows 7 os. 
Is there an extension or method available so I could place the custom options e.g. Door size, for export-import, in there own column in a spreadsheet for editing?
thanks in advance